# Multiple @Input property in Child Component not getting binded in Angular application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bind multiple input properties in the child component i.e. IsMandatory & SelectedValue. I have done very thing correct, not able to figure out why Selectedvalue input property not getting binded.

Here is the [link for the source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materia-select?file=src/app/select-value-binding-example.ts). Please let me know what I'm missing out here.IsMandtory input property is getting binded correctly but SelectedValue is not getting binded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input SelectedValue's type has been declared as a string.
So, in select-container.html, Angular expects to find [SelectedValue]="-->a string<--". You were right so far.

But the mistake you made was setting [SelectedValue]="option2", which makes Angular look for a variable named option2 in select-container.ts, but since it doesn't find any, undefined is passed to SelectedValue. Thus, undefined is logged in the console.

FIX:

1. [SelectedValue] = "'option2'" (Note that inside the " ", option2 is enclosed once more in ' '. This helps Angular understand that a string is being passed!). This is generally not a good practice.
2. [SelectedValue] = "mySelectedOption" where mySelectedOption is a variable declared in select-container.ts and initialized to the string 'option2', in your case. This is the recommended approach. (note that mySelectedOption is only enclosed in " " and there are no ' ' as it's a variable.)

BONUS: You might be wondering why [isMandatory]="false" worked. Why didn't Angular think false was a variable too and check for it in select-container.ts? The reason is that false/true are reserved keywords for Angular and you're not allowed to use them as variables. So Angular automatically knows that false is a value, not a variable, and passes it on to isMandatory as expected.

Hope the answer helps!

Comment: Thank you pradyuma.